# polipo E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: installation, polipo

```
@me:/home$ sudo apt-get install polipo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
polipo
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 198 kB of archives.
After this operation, 799 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://sy.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe polipo amd64 
1.0.4.1-1.1 [198 kB]
    Fetched 198 kB in 2s (97.5 kB/s)                        
    Selecting previously unselected package polipo.
    (Reading database ... 169595 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking polipo (from .../polipo_1.0.4.1-1.1_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for doc-base ...
Processing 1 added doc-base file...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for install-info ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up polipo (1.0.4.1-1.1) ...
Starting polipo: Couldn't open config file /etc/polipo/config: 2.
invoke-rc.d: initscript polipo, action "start" failed.
****dpkg: error processing polipo (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
polipo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)****
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might with your config file. I would recommend you to back the original config file `/etc/polipo/config` and download the config file provided by `torbrowser`.

Here is the steps

```
sudo mv /etc/polipo/config /etc/polipo/config.orig
sudo wget https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob/ae4aa49ad9100a50eec049d0a419fac63a84d874:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf \
-O /etc/polipo/config
```

Now try to rerun the command

```
sudo apt-get install polipo
```

Hope this helps

Comment: i did not change the original config file .. the only steps i did are :
1- apt-get install tor ( and its working very well )
2- and when i install Polipo its giving me this error is its start dpkg ?

Comment: Yeah I understood. Backup the `/etc/polipo/config` file and follow the steps I mentioned.

Comment: its giving me 

Starting polipo: /etc/polipo/config:1: parse error.
/etc/polipo/config:2: parse error.
p

Comment: please i need help !~

Comment: Do the following `sudo mv /etc/polipo/config /etc/polipo/config.orig` and then `sudo wget https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob/ae4aa49ad9100a50eec049d0a419fac63a84d874:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf \
-O /etc/polipo/config` after these two steps now do the installation once again. `sudo apt-get install polipo`

Comment: i need to clear something before /etc/polipo/ ls :
config config.orig forbidden options 

and yes am following the commands you are giving me and once i run the command sudo apt-get install polipo i have the problem when it start dpkg .. all  parse errors !!!! how can i roll back the entire process and start all over for polipo ... further i can not find any back file  config file provided by torbrowser ?

Comment: Are you able to move the file using command `sudo mv /etc/polipo/config /etc/polipo/config.orig`?

Comment: the both files ( config , config.orig ) are in the same directory /etc/polipo/

Comment: Were you able to get the file from https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob/ae4aa49ad9100a50eec049d0a419fa‌​c63a84d874:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf

Comment: the file is deleted i couldnt find it there

Comment: Download the file from here https://gitweb.torproject.org/torbrowser.git/blob_plain/ae4aa49ad9100a50eec049d0a419fac63a84d874:/build-scripts/config/polipo.conf

Comment: i ve got the same problem :
error polipo E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 0):

I get the error because I uninstall polipo and rm the config file in /etc/polipo/.

I fix it follow:

just run commands step by step:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt update 

sudo apt upgrade
```

refer: https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/